# How to click a .class random # of times

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I need to click a .CLASS random number of times on between 1 and 10, on keypress
I'm guessing I need to use `Math.floor(Math.random())` function but not sure how to integrate it with the function I already have, I'm pretty new to this.
Thank you in advance.

```
(function(tags) {
    tags = ["INPUT", "SELECT", "TEXTAREA"];
    addEventListener("keydown", function(ev, ele) {
        if (ev.shiftKey || ev.ctrlKey || ev.altKey || tags.includes(ev.target.tagName)) return;
        switch (ev.key.toUpperCase()) {
            case "Z": // test
                if (ele = document.querySelector(".CLASS")) ele.click();
                break;
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: What do you mean by click?

Comment: You mean you have to simulate a click on the element?

Comment: If second statement is true you can generate random int and use for loop (from 0 to random int) to click the element or you can fire function that is calling from click event.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
if (ele = document.querySelector(".CLASS") {
    let count = Math.floor(Math.random() % 10) + 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        e.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example

```
<button class="button_example">Random Button 1</button>
<button class="button_example">Random Button 2</button>
<button class="button_example">Random Button 3</button>
<button class="button_example">Random Button 4</button>
<button class="button_example">Random Button 5</button>
<button class="button_example">Random Button 6</button>
<button class="button_example">Random Button 7</button>
<button class="button_example">Random Button 8</button>
<button class="button_example">Random Button 9</button>
<button class="button_example">Random Button 10</button>

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button_example');
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length);
buttons[randomNumber].click();
```

Comment: He said random number of times, not a random button.